# Mirror a binary tree in constant time

Tags: algorithm, tree, big-o

This is not a homework question. I heard that it is possible to mirror a binary tree i.e. flip it, in constant time. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, depending on your data structure, you would just do the equivalent of: instead of traversing down the left node and then the right node, you would traverse down the right node, and then the left node. This could be a parameter passed into the recursive function that traverses the tree (i.e. in C/C++, a `bool bDoLeftFirst`, and an if-statement that uses that parameter to decide which order to traverse the child nodes in).

Comment: Isn't this O(n) since you traverse the whole tree? OP asks for constant time

Comment: It could be not left/right nodes but a/b nodes, and the parameter will define whether a is left or right, hence constant time

Comment: @cricket_007 - I think the point is that the "mirroring" is separate from the traversal. To avoid pedanting arguments you might make the which-direction flag part of the data structure, defining the roles of the child pointers. It's O(1) to toggle the flag therefore O(1) to redefine the roles of the child pointers. All that makes the left-child pointer *be* a left-child pointer is the name and how you use it - change those and there's no reason the roles can't change at run-time as defined by a flag that's also part of the data structure.

Comment: @Steve314 - I agree reassigning pointers is O(1), but you can't do that for just the root and call it a day, you'll still need to do that for every non-leaf node, therefore I still think it's O(n).

Comment: @cricket_007 - that's just it - you *don't* reassign anything except that one flag. The pointers stay the same, but they take different roles because that's what the flag defines. You don't have a left-child pointer and a right-child pointer, you have a left-child-if-flag-is-true-else-right-child pointer and a right-child-if-flag-is-true-else-left-child pointer. The logical meaning of the tree is mirrored even though only the flag has changed in memory - though you don't see that until you e.g. traverse it with a traversal function that's aware of that flag.

Comment: I was under the assumption either a new tree object is formed or modify the existing tree reference. But yeah, I see what you're saying. I even extended the thought to an enum for pre-order, post-order, and in-order traversal.

Comment: @cricket_007 - "When I use a word," Humpty Dumpty said in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean - neither more nor less." - but remember what happened to him. Make sure you're doing it for a good reason and remember to explain what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean "invert binary tree", the problem which Max Howell could not solve and thus rejected by Google?

https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/

You can find solutions in the "discuss" section.

Comment: What I meant is inversion, but no solutions discussed there are O(1).

Comment: @ayberkt I don't think you can do that in O(1).

Comment: @ayberkt You have to traverse at least one sub tree either iteratively or recursively, which takes at least O(h) time.